# PHP Kohana3. Can I rename ORM object properties?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm using Kohana3.
For example I create instance:
`$user = ORM::factory('orm_user', $user_id)`
After this I can get value of each column using this syntax: `$user->user_login` or `$user->user_password`.
Can I rename this properties to get them like: `$user->login` or `$user->pass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can overload the magic __set and __get methods in your model:

```
public function __get($field)
{
    switch ($field) {
        case 'login':
            return $this->user_login;
        case 'pass':
            return $this->user_password;
    }

    return parent::__get($field);
}

public function __set($field, $value)
{
    switch ($field) {
        case 'login':
            $this->user_login = $value;
            return;
        case 'pass':
            $this->user_password = $value;
            return;
    }

    parent::__set($field, $value);
}
```

Any rules or filters you write will still need to use the original column names.